# How to make async function yield on block?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I just started learning asynchronous Rust, so this is propably not a difficult question to answer, however, I am scratching my head here.

I am not trying to run tasks in parallel yet, only trying to get them to run concurrently.

According to the guide at https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/,

> The futures::join macro makes it possible to wait for multiple different futures to complete while executing them all concurrently.

So when I create 2 Futures, I should be able to "await" both of them at once. It also states that

> Whereas calling a blocking function in a synchronous method would block the whole thread, blocked Futures will yield control of the thread, allowing other Futures to run.

From what I understand here, if I await multiple Futures with join!, should the first one be blocked, the second one will start running.

So I made a very simple example where I created 2 async fns and tried to join! both, making sure the first one gets blocked. I used a mpsc::channel for the blocking, since the docs stated that thread::sleep() should not be used in async fns and that recv()

> will always block the current thread if there is no data available

However, the behavior is not what I expected, as calling the blocking function will not yield control of the thread, allowing the other Future to run, like I would expect from the second quote I provided. Instead, it will just wait untill it is no longer blocked, finish the first Future and only then start the second. Pretty much as if they were synchronous and I would have just called one after the other.

My complete example code:

```
use std::{thread::{self}, sync::{mpsc::{self, Sender, Receiver}}, time::Duration};
use futures::{executor};                 //added futures = "0.3" in cargo.toml dependencies
fn main(){ 
    let fut = main_async();
    executor::block_on(fut);
}


async fn main_async(){
    let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
    let thread_handle = std::thread::spawn(move || {              //this thread is just here so the f1 function gets blocked by something and can later resume
        wait_send_function(sender);
    });
    let f1 = f1(receiver);
    let f2 = f2();
    futures::join!(f1, f2);
    thread_handle.join().unwrap();
}

fn wait_send_function(sender: Sender<i32>){
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(5000));
    sender.send(1234).unwrap();
}


async fn f1(receiver: Receiver<i32>){
    println!("starting f1");
    let new_nmbr = receiver.recv().unwrap();               //I would expect f2 to start now, since this is blocking
    println!("Received nmbr is: {}", new_nmbr);
}

async fn f2(){
    println!("starting f2");
}
```

And the output is simply:

```
starting f1
Received nmbr is: 1234
starting f2
```

My question is what am I missing here, why does f2 only start after f1 is completed and what would I need to do to get the behavior I want (completing f2 first if f1 is blocked and then waiting for f1)?

Comment: The implementation of channel in `std::sync::mpsc` is not aware of async, so running `receiver.recv()` blocks the calling thread until it receives. Since `futures::executor::block_on` runs the future on a single-threaded executor and the thread is blocked, `f1` does not get a chance to run before `f2` returns. You may want to use channels designed for async like [`futures_channel`](https://crates.io/crates/futures-channel).

Comment: Thank you, @kotatsuyaki
By changing the channel type to futures_channel::oneshot::channel(), I could get the behavior I expected, when I tried to receive with "let new_nmbr = receiver.await.unwrap();"

However, I am kind of surprised, since I looked at std::sync::mpsc::channel before and it says:
"Creates a new asynchronous channel, returning the sender/receiver halves"
I assumed this meant, I could use it in this case.

Comment: The [module-level documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/) of `std::sync::mpsc` only states that *sends* are asynchronous and do not block, so it is perfectly fine for *receives* to block. Also FYI, in async Rust the only places where yield happen are the `.await` points, so if there is no `.await` then it is not going to yield.

Comment: Thank you again @kotatsuyaki !
I guess then, that the second quote I provided from the rust async guide at
[link](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/04_async_await_primer.html)
is kind of misleading, and is not talking about what is usually meant by blocking, but instead of async primitives that block the current task and wakeup another one if available? (Like in `receiver.await`)

Comment: I think in that link I'd separate the concept of a blocked future vs a blocked function. A blocked future means the function ran synchronously then decided it could not proceed and exited in a blocked state (but did exit, meaning other code could run on that thread instead), where a blocked function is code that is explicitly in the process of running, meaning the thread is performing that and only that operation and no other code may run on the thread until it is completed.

Comment: An async function returns a Future, but the function's body code hasn't actually run yet, it is the underlying logic that awaits the future that handles that (e.g. `tokio` or some other executor), and when an async function `.await`s something, it is conceptually as if the function returned (back to that underlying logic, since it is what called it), but did so in such a way that it can resume execution of the function later.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the book is a little misleading, but when it refers to "a blocked future", it *does not* mean in the sense of blocking synchronous code (if that was the case, there would be no problem to use `std::thread::sleep()`), but rather, it means that the future is waiting to be polled by the executor.

Thus, `std::mpsc` that blocks the thread will not have the desired effect (definitely not on a single-threaded executor like `future`'s, but it's a bad idea on multi-threaded executors too). Use [`futures::channel::mpsc`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/channel/mpsc/index.html) and everything will work.

Comment: Thank you, @Chayim Friedmann !

I looked more into polling and why the poll function is necessary to implement the Future trait and I think I understand the fundamental concepts.
I was wondering, how to solve this example if relying on an external crate was not an option. I was able to by Wrapping the original mpsc::channel in a new struct that implements Future and thus polls the result of try_recv() and a corresponding Sender that wakes up my task once it is done. 
Which then worked (for this specific example) exactly as I expected the program in my original question would.

Comment: @Saetch If relying on external crates is not an option then you cannot probably use `async`. You can always roll your own, but `async` requires a lot from libraries (you don't even have an executor).

Comment: yes, @Chayim Friedmann, 
 you are right. This was more of a "understanding the concept" type of excercise I did. Using futures_channel as kotatsuyaki suggested is obviously the right choice here.

I am actually kind of surprised that Rust doesn't provide a standard executor at all.